# React запись данных в state после запроса fetch

Tags: reactjs, fetch

Добрых времени суток, имеется данный код:

```
class Data extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      titles: ''
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let status = function(response) {
      if(response.status !== 200) {
        return Promise.reject(new Error(response.statusText))
      }
      return Promise.resolve(response)
    }

    let json = function(response) {
      return response.json()
    }

    fetch('http://www.mocky.io/v2/5bdb4bd63200009e243ad51d')
    .then(status)
    .then(json)
    .then(function(data) {
      var titleName = data.map((title) => {
        return (
          <div className="test">
            <p>{title.body}</p>
          </div>
        );
      })
    })
    this.setState({titles: titleName})
    console.log('state => ', this.state.titles)
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log('error', error)
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>{this.state.nameTitle}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Данные:

```
[
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
    "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "qui est esse",
    "body": "est rerum tempore vitae\nsequi sint nihil reprehenderit dolor beatae ea dolores neque\nfugiat blanditiis voluptate porro vel nihil molestiae ut reiciendis\nqui aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 3,
    "title": "ea molestias quasi exercitationem repellat qui ipsa sit aut",
    "body": "et iusto sed quo iure\nvoluptatem occaecati omnis eligendi aut ad\nvoluptatem doloribus vel accusantium quis pariatur\nmolestiae porro eius odio et labore et velit aut"
  }
]
```

Как записать полученные данные в state(например title), чтобы их потом использовать в компонентах? 
**Выдаёт ошибку: 'titleName' is not defined  no-undef**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 час и пару чашек кофе "подарили" мне решение:

```
class Data extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      titles: ''
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('http://www.mocky.io/v2/5bdb709a320000cc293ad582')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      this.setState({titles: data[0].title})
      console.log(data)
      console.log('state => ', this.state.titles)
    })
    .catch(error => console.error(error))
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>{this.state.titles}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Сам спросил, сам ответил)